# Proxmox apt-get update fails

Tags: server, virtual-machine, proxmox

When I type in the bash of the Server apt-get update it fails, I don't know why. The error is:

> E: Failed to fetch https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/pve/dists/buster/InRelease  401  Unauthorized [IP: 2a01:7e0:0:424::249 443]
>
> E: The repository 'https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/pve buster InRelease' is not signed.
>
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
>
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 8):

The **apt** package manager on the fresh Proxmox host is configured to download packages from **Enterprise Repository** by default. You must have a paid subscription to use this repo. If you don't have paid subscription you should switch to **No-Subscription Repository**.

Either delete `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pve-enterprise.list` file or comment all lines in this file with `#`.

Create new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pve-no-subscription.list` with content:

```
deb http://download.proxmox.com/debian/pve buster pve-no-subscription
```

Read about Proxmox package repositories here:
https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Package_Repositories

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer when looking for a solution to similar GPG errors when trying to update Proxmox while running the Debug terminal during a fresh install. This is a rather old question, but I haven't found a better place to give a more detailed answer other than the Proxmox forums.

As Moayad Almalat says above, you need to buy an Enterprise subscription or disable that repository and add the `pve-no-subscription` repository instead.
This is the easiest one-line command to add the no-sub repo (don't forget to remove or disable the enterprise repo though):

```bash
echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://download.proxmox.com/debian/pve $(lsb_release -s -c) pve-no-subscription" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pve-no-sub-repo.list
```

Once those changes are made, you need to make sure your GPG Keys for the new repositories are in place:

```bash
wget https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/proxmox-release-$(lsb_release -s -c).gpg -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/proxmox-release-$(lsb_release -s -c).gpg

wget http://download.proxmox.com/debian/proxmox-ve-release-5.x.gpg -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/proxmox-ve-release-5.x.gpg
```

If you still have GPG issues when trying to run `apt update`, you can make sure the GPG keys have the proper permissions by using:

```bash
chmod +r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/proxmox-release-$(lsb_release -s -c).gpg

chmod +r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/proxmox-ve-release-5.x.gpg
```

Again, as Moayad Almalat mentioned, you can read most of this on the Proxmox wiki here: https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Package_Repositories